# Parsing div with jsoup

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I've this part of HTML code:

```
...
<div class="K9wGie">
   <div class="BHMmbe" aria-label="Rated 4.6 stars out of five stars">4.6</div>
   <div class="LvvOW">
    <div aria-label="Rated 4.6 stars out of five stars" role="img">
       <div class="BGNhFb WF1WQd"></div>
       <div class="BGNhFb WF1WQd"></div>
   <span class="EymY4b">
     <span class="O3QoBc hzfjkd"></span>
     <span class="" aria-label="2,749 ratings">2,749</span> total</span></div>
...
```

I want to take value "4.6" from second div, and value "2,749" from last span. How can i do it with jsoup?

Tried with `document.select("div[aria-label]").text()` but it returns this string: `"Read more Collapse 4.6  Read more Collapse".` I dont even see these words in this block, but this html code just a small part of huge document.

Tried with `document.select("div.K9wGie").first().parent().text()` and this returns following string: `"4.6 2,758 total 5 4 3 2 1"`.

Tried with

```
document.select("div.K9wGie").first().parent()
                .select("span").first().text();
```

It returns `2,761 total`. So close, but i dont need this "total" word. Of course, later, i can use replace string methods if other solution will not be found, but want to do it with jsoup. And still no solution for value "4.6".

I'm close to find solution, but can't beat it.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tpZ3.png)

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g010P.png)

Comment: "but it returns this string" no it doesn't. At least not on the HTML code you're showing, and you should prove that to yourself by literally running that code on the exact HTML you're showing and seeing it return "4.6"

Comment: Its a google play link, its only a part of big html code (what a said). I copied this html code from browser console. It's a div block "Ratings". And added screens to prove my output.

Comment: Right, but if you're showing code: [show code that has the problem you describe](/help/how-to-ask). And if you have _lots_ of code, [reduce that code first](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Right now, your post does not show a problem: the Java code you're showing _will_ find the text you say you need, given the HTML you're showing, so we have nothing to contribute: this works, there is no problem to solve.